# invoke https cert authenticated service in Strongloop Loopback using datasource.json

Tags: ssl, https, loopbackjs, strongloop, client-certificates

I have 2 node.js applications(App1 and App2) created in **strongloop loopback**, both are protected using the **x509 certificate**(key, cert, ca and password).

App1 needs to invoke a REST endpoint exposed by App2, using the [datasource.json](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/REST-connector.html#configure-options-for-request). As per the documentation loopback uses the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol) and [datasource.json](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest#configure-options-for-request)

How to pass the options object using datasource.json ?

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://api.some-server.com/',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
    key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
    passphrase: 'password',
    ca: fs.readFileSync(caFile)
};
```

Comment: if you look at the link it mentioned `You can configure options options property at two levels:

Data source level (common to all operations)
Operation level (specific to the declaring operation)` and if you configure for app1 you can use this to communicate

Comment: I had tried to add the options at the operation level, but it was giving me an error from the request module. When I tried to invoke the service using the same options object using the request module(without datasource.json), it was working.